# How to count with multiple condition in R

Tags: r

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R:

```
Id     rule1   rule2
o1     1       0
o2     1       1
o3     1       0
o4     0       1
```

I want to add one more column as `rule3` where if rule1 and rule2 are 1 then it should be b, if rule1 is 0 and rule2 is 1 it should be a and if rule 1 is 1 and rule2 is 0 it should be c.

```
Id     rule1   rule2   rule3
o1     0       1       a
o2     0       1       a
o3     1       1       b
o4     1       0       c
```

I'm using the following code, but it is not working.

```
df1$rule3 <- ifelse(df1$rule1=1 && df1$rule2=1, "c", 0)
```

And how to count basis a,b and c.

Comment: You need a double equals sign: `==` for comparison, otherwise you are assigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, using nested `ifelse` statement you can do :

```
transform(df, rule3 = ifelse(rule1 == 1 & rule2 == 1, 'b', 
                         ifelse(rule1 == 0 & rule2 == 1, 'a', 
                                ifelse(rule1 == 1 & rule2 == 0, 'c', NA))))

#  Id rule1 rule2 rule3
#1 o1     0     1     a
#2 o2     0     1     a
#3 o3     1     1     b
#4 o4     1     0     c
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = structure(1:4, .Label = c("o1", "o2", "o3", 
"o4"), class = "factor"), rule1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), rule2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, How to use `rule3` values in count I'm using `pivot<- dcast(df, a1_status_start_date.x ~ "rule3", value.var = df$rule = "c", fun.aggregate = sum)`

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do here and what is your expected output. Not sure what is `a1_status_start_date.x` or `df$rule` etc.

Comment: Shahk, That is noting but a column with date.

Comment: The expected output I'm trying to get is aggregate count where rule3 = "c".

Comment: Please can you ask this as a new question as I think this is not related to the question you have posted here and I am finding it difficult to understand through comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `dplyr` `mutate` with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  rule1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
  rule2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0)
)

mutate(df, rule3 = case_when(
  rule1 == 0 & rule2 == 1 ~ "a",
  (rule1 & rule2) == 1 ~ "b",
  rule1 == 1 & rule2 == 0 ~ "c",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_
))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  rule1 rule2 rule3
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     0     1 a    
2     0     1 a    
3     1     1 b    
4     1     0 c
```